# Related post by category, but only one

Tags: wordpress, related-content

I'm using this code to display related post by category and it works fine if there is only one category. But in the case of multiple categories I only want to use one, the first one. How do I limit this to just one category?

```
 function related_posts_categories() {    
        $categories = get_the_category();
        if ($categories) {
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $cat = $category->cat_ID;
        $args=array(
        'cat' => $cat,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page'=>4,
        'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1
        );
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<div id="related_posts"><h3>Related Content</h3><ul>';
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
             <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
             <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'related-posts' ); ?>
             </a>
             <div class="related_content">
             <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
             </div>
            </li>
         <?php
        endwhile;
        }
        echo '</ul></div>';
        }} wp_reset_query(); }
```

Comment: Why are you using a `foreach($categories as $category)` if you only want the first one?

Comment: @GerardReches it doesn't seem to work correctly without the foreach loop. I don't get content from the category that matches the post, just the most recent content.